# Can't find tables with activeJDBC in H2 non-default schema

Tags: h2, database-schema, activejdbc

In my integration test, I am creating an H2 database with two schemas, `A` and `B`. `A` is set as the default schema, like it is in the normal setup for the application when it is running with a PostgreSQL database. During the integration test, I am starting both the H2 database and an embedded Tomcat server and execute the SQL files to initialise the database via Liquibase.

All models that are connected to tables in schema `A` are annotated with `@Table("tablename")`, whereas models for schema `B` are annotated with `@Table("B.tablename")`. When I call a REST endpoint in the embedded server, activeJDBC warns me:

```
WARN  org.javalite.activejdbc.Registry - Failed to retrieve metadata for table: 'B.tablename'. Are you sure this table exists? For some databases table names are case sensitive.
```

When I then try to access a table in schema `B` in my Java code, activeJDBC throws the following exception (which is expected after the previous warning):

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.InitException: Failed to find table: B.tablename
  at org.javalite.activejdbc.MetaModel.getAttributeNames(MetaModel.java:248)
  at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.hydrate(Model.java:207)
  at org.javalite.activejdbc.ModelDelegate.instance(ModelDelegate.java:247)
  at org.javalite.activejdbc.ModelDelegate.instance(ModelDelegate.java:241)
  ...
```

Accessing tables in schema `A` works as expected.

I am sure that the tables in schema `B` are actually created and contain data, because on top of Liquibase log entries for executing the files I can also access the database directly and get the table content as a result:

Initialisation of Database and server:

```
private String H2_CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS A\\;SET SCHEMA A\\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS B\\;";

@Before
public void initializeDatabase() {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(H2_CONNECTION_STRING);
    Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
    stat.execute("GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA TO PUBLIC");
    LiquibaseInitialisation.initH2(H2_CONNECTION_STRING); // execute SQL scripts
    EmbeddedServer.startServer();
}
```

Query to print content of `B.tablename`:

```
Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test");

Statement stat = connection.createStatement(); 
stat.execute("SELECT * FROM B.tablename;");
connection.commit();

resultSet = stat4.getResultSet();
rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        builder.append(resultSet.getString(i));
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    Log.info(builder.toString());
}
```

This produces the desired output of the content of `B.tablename`.

The question is this: Why doesn't activeJDBC find the tables in schema `B` in the H2 database when it's clearly present, but works flawlessly in PostgreSQL? Am I missing something with regards to schemas in H2 or activeJDBC?

Comment: how do you access a different schema in PostreSQL?

Comment: @ipolevoy By annotating the model class with `@Table("B.tablename")`, which works as desired in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, log this as an issue: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues and provide full instructions to replicate this condition. Best if you can provide a small project.

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/707) and added an example project which reproduces the error.